# auto keyword together with smartpointers?

Tags: c++

I can :

```
auto o1 = new Content;
```

But can't:

```
std::shared_ptr<auto> o1(new Content);
std::unique_ptr<auto> o1(new Content);
```

What I should do?

Comment: `auto o1 = make_unique<Content>();`?

Comment: Note that you can't write `std::shared_ptr o1(new Content);`. In general, it's now legal to omit the template argument when it can be deduced, but you can't choose between `shared_ptr<Content[]>` and `shared_ptr<Content>` given just a `T*`. (Search "C++ Template Deduction Guides"  for details )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `make_shared`/`make_unique` like this:

```
auto o1 = std::make_shared<Content>(); // Pass any arguments here as you would normally.
auto o2 = std::make_unique<Content>(); // Pass any arguments here as you would normally.
```

These functions forward all arguments to the constructor of (in this case) `Content`, you can use `auto` and you only have to write the type once.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

```
auto o1 = std::make_unique<Content>();
auto o2 = std::make_shared<Content>();
```